Ubuntu 22 laptop HP camera not working
This is the my system information

My laptop camera ubuntu is not working.
Please provide some fix that can help me

Please try 24.04. It has better support for recently released hardware

okay are you sure that it will work?

I don't know. Please try it, it may work

okay let me check
